# prepend word before every function argument

Tags: repeated-commands

accidentally just wrote

```
void foo(bar, baz, que) {
```

and forgot to specify type, I want to convert the above to

```
void foo(String bar, String baz, String que) {
```

How can I do that quickly?

Answer (score 1):

Define "quickly".

Easiest way for me:

`/bar<cr>iString <esc>WW.WW.`

Another one would be:

`V:s/b/String b/g`

Answer (score 1):

I handle such situations using macros

1) move cursor to right place:

```
void foo(bar, baz, que) {
         ^
```

2) Start writing macros to some buffer. For example - buffer "e" `qe`

3) correct one argument and move cursor to another `iString <esc>WW`

```
void foo(String bar, baz, que) {
                     ^
```

4) Stop macros execution `q`

5) Execute macros two more times `2@e`

```
void foo(String bar, String baz, String que) {
                                             ^
```

Total input from right position `qeiString <esc>WW2@e`. Where `<esc>` is escape key.